# Moving Bones in X-Mirror Mode not working (Bones jump to other side)

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

As can be seen in the pictures below, I created a simple Blender rig and moved the bones using X-Mirror mode (Top right). It worked fine until I reopened the project today. As soon as I move a bone, the other one immediately snaps over.

Pls help :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparently I had to turn armature + model by 90 degrees and apply rotation in object mode..